# How will I pass ranges instead of iterator-pairs in C++20?

Tags: c++, range, c++20

I've heard that C++20 will support acting on ranges, not just begin+end iterator pairs. Does that mean that, in C++20, I'll be able to write:

```
std::vector<int> vec = get_vector_from_somewhere();
std::sort(vec);
std::vector<float> halves; 
halves.reserve(vec.size());
std::transform(
    vec, std::back_inserter(halves),
    [](int x) { return x * 0.5; }
);
```

?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

#### Almost, yes!

You'll just need to use the `std::ranges::` namespace instead of just `std::`; at least, this is what Eric Niebler [says](http://ericniebler.com/2018/12/05/standard-ranges/) in his blog post. So, you would write:

```
std::vector<int> vec = get_vector_from_somewhere();
std::ranges::sort(vec);
std::vector<float> halves; 
halves.reserve(vec.size());
std::ranges::transform(
    vec, std::back_inserter(halves),
    [](int x) { return x * 0.5; }
);
```

You can also have a look at the [cppreference page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/ranges/all_any_none_of) on `std::all_of` (and `none_of` and `any_of`) for a detailed example of C++20-style  `<algorithm>` code; but not all of these pages have been written in on cppreference.com .

---

As @Barry notes, if we could use `ranges::to` (which we can't in C++20, but can in C++23) we can make that even simpler:

```
std::vector<int> vec = get_vector_from_somewhere();
std::ranges::sort(vec);
auto halves = vec
    | std::ranges::view::transform([](int x){ return x * 0.5; }) 
    | ranges::to<std::vector<float>>;
```

Comment: I'm not very familiar with the ranges library, but from the examples, it seems you might be able to express this code very compactly in only 1 or 2 lines using the pipeline syntax. It would be great to see an example of that, if it's possible.

Comment: @alterigel: I'm not fully familiar with it myself; and you may be right - although I specifically wanted to use syntax similar to the existing one.

Comment: `auto halves = vec | view::transform([](int x){ return x * 0.5; }) | ranges::to<std::vector<float>>;` (`view::transform` will be in C++20, `ranges::to` won't be but you can just borrow it from range-v3)

Comment: @Barry: Well, you can't  "just borrow" it, it has a bunch of dependencies within range-v3. Also, it's `to_` IIANM.

Comment: @einpoklum You're right, it's `to_`. By borrow it from range-v3, I meant use range-v3 - not like... cut that specific thing out of it.

Comment: @Barry minor typo: `ranges::to_<std::vector<float>>` requires `()` or `{}` at the end, to create an object.